# Code optimize, how to make it look good

Tags: javascript

Today, I code some JavaScript, but it really does not look good. So how can I optimize it with good extend and look delicious

```
if($("#active-flg").val() == 'clubInfo') {
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(0)").addClass("active");
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(1)").removeClass("active");
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(2)").removeClass("active");

    $("#manage-club-info").addClass("active");
    $("#manage-club-config").removeClass("active");
    $("#manage-club-phone").removeClass("active");

} else if($("#active-flg").val() == 'clubSeo') {
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(0)").removeClass("active");
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(1)").addClass("active");
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(2)").removeClass("active");

    $("#manage-club-info").removeClass("active");
    $("#manage-club-seo").addClass("active");
    $("#manage-club-phone").removeClass("active");

} else if($("#active-flg").val() == 'clubPhone') {
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(0)").removeClass("active");
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(1)").removeClass("active");
    $("[name='local-li']:eq(2)").addClass("active");

    $("#manage-club-info").removeClass("active");
    $("#manage-club-seo").removeClass("active");
    $("#manage-club-phone").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: If the code is working and you want to get it reviewed, [codereview.se] is the place to ask.

Comment: @NattyQ can you also share the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this is not code review,

```
var flags = ['clubInfo', 'clubSeo', 'clubPhone']
var targets = ['#manage-club-info','#manage-club-seo','#manage-club-phone'] 
var val = $("#active-flg").val();
var index = flags.indexOf(val);

if (index >= 0){
    $("[name='local-li']").removeClass("active");
    $(targets.join(',')).removeClass("active");

    var activeLi = "[name='local-li']:eq("+ index +")";
    $(activeLi).addClass("active");
    $(targets[index]).addClass("active");    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
if($("#active-flg").val() == 'clubInfo') {
    removeClass(["[name='local-li']:eq(1)","[name='local-li']:eq(2)","#manage-club-config","#manage-club-phone"]);
    addClass(["[name='local-li']:eq(0)","#manage-club-info"])

} else if($("#active-flg").val() == 'clubSeo') {
    removeClass(["[name='local-li']:eq(0)","[name='local-li']:eq(2)","#manage-club-info","#manage-club-phone"]);
    addClass(["[name='local-li']:eq(1)","#manage-club-seo"])

} else if($("#active-flg").val() == 'clubPhone') {
    removeClass(["[name='local-li']:eq(0)","[name='local-li']:eq(1)","#manage-club-info","#manage-club-seo"]);
    addClass(["[name='local-li']:eq(2)","#manage-club-phone"]);
}


function addClass(arraySelectors){
    for (selector in arraySelectors){
        $(arraySelectors[selector]).addClass("active");
    }
}

function removeClass(arraySelectors){
    for (selector in arraySelectors){
        $(arraySelectors[selector]).removeClass("active");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
var actions = {
    clubInfo: function(){
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(0)").addClass("active");
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(1)").removeClass("active");
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(2)").removeClass("active");

        $("#manage-club-info").addClass("active");
        $("#manage-club-config").removeClass("active");
        $("#manage-club-phone").removeClass("active");

    },
    clubSeo: function(){
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(0)").removeClass("active");
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(1)").addClass("active");
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(2)").removeClass("active");

        $("#manage-club-info").removeClass("active");
        $("#manage-club-seo").addClass("active");
        $("#manage-club-phone").removeClass("active");
    },
    clubPhone: function(){
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(0)").removeClass("active");
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(1)").removeClass("active");
        $("[name='local-li']:eq(2)").addClass("active");

        $("#manage-club-info").removeClass("active");
        $("#manage-club-seo").removeClass("active");
        $("#manage-club-phone").addClass("active");
    }
}
var action = $("#active-flg").val();
if(actions[action]) {
    actions[action]();
} else {
    sexyDefaultFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is multiple kinds of redundant, which isn't good. One of the most fundamental reasons computers exist is to eliminate redundancy.

What you want to be doing is finding ways to iterate over the things you have recursively and leaving the redundancy up to the computer or better yet just sidestepping redundancy and only dealing with the values that you need to. AKA instead of:

```
if(var == "bread") {
    $("#bread").addClass("active");
}

if(var == "milk") {
    $("#milk").addClass("active");
}

if(var == "eggs") {
    $("#eggs").addClass("active");
}
```

You want something like:

```
$("#" + var).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Not so much my ideas so much as fundamental aspects of computer science, no problem though! These things kinda come into context the more you do.